# enhance woodwind diagram for eight holes

Tags: lilypond

[image: example hole diagram]
Hi there,
A code for changing woodwind diagram from six holes into seven holes is shown below.
Can someone help to change it to eight holes as shown in picture below?

```
\version "2.22.1"
% LilyBin
#(define-markup-command
  (woodwind-diagram-x layout props 
   instrument user-draw-commands)
  (symbol? list?)
  #:properties ((upper-hole1 #f)
   (size 1)
                (thickness 0.1)
                (graphical #t))
  (let* ((ww-diagram
          (interpret-markup layout props
            (make-woodwind-diagram-markup
             instrument user-draw-commands)))
         (hole-circle
          (make-circle-stencil size thickness upper-hole1))
         (midline
          (make-line-stencil (* thickness 2) (* -0.80 size) 0 (* 0.80 size) 0))
         (upper-circle-and-midline
          (ly:stencil-combine-at-edge hole-circle Y DOWN midline (* 0.80 size))))
    (ly:stencil-combine-at-edge
     upper-circle-and-midline Y DOWN ww-diagram (* 0.80 size))
    ))
\markup {
  \center-column {
  \override #'(upper-hole1. #f) 
    \override #'(size . 0.7) {
      \woodwind-diagram-x #'flute
      #'((cc . (oneF two three four five six))
         (lh . ())
         (rh . ()))
    }
  }
}
\markup \vspace #2.0
\markup {
  \center-column {
   \override #'(upper-hole1 . #t)
    \override #'(size . 0.7) {
      \woodwind-diagram-x #'flute
      #'((cc . (oneF two three four five six))
         (lh . ())
         (rh . ()))
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The original woodwind diagrams are quite difficult to customize, since they include some kind of user interface that allows you to individually select the (half-) closed holes. But you could draw your own diagrams, for example like follows (with inspiration from [here](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/lilypond-user/2017-11/msg00521.html)):

```
\version "2.18.2"

wwOpenHole = \markup {
  \with-dimensions #'(-0.5 . 0.5) #'(-0.5 . 0.5)
  \postscript #"
    0.15 setlinewidth
    0.5 0 moveto
    0 0 0.5 0 360 arc
    closepath stroke"
}

wwClosedHole = \markup {
  \with-dimensions #'(-0.5 . 0.5) #'(-0.5 . 0.5)
  \postscript #"
    0.15 setlinewidth
    0.5 0 moveto
    0 0 0.5 0 360 arc
    closepath stroke
    0.15 setlinewidth
    0.5 0 moveto
    0 0 0.5 0 360 arc
    closepath fill"
}

wwHalfHole = \markup {
  \with-dimensions #'(-0.5 . 0.5) #'(-0.5 . 0.5)
  \postscript #"
    0.15 setlinewidth
    0.5 0 moveto
    0 0 0.5 0 360 arc
    closepath stroke
    0 0.5 moveto
    0 0 0.5 90 270 arc
    0 0.5 lineto
    closepath fill"
}

wwDiaLower = \markup {
  \center-column { 
    \vspace #-0.5 \draw-line #' ( 1.5 . 0)
    \vspace #-0.5 \wwClosedHole
    \vspace #-0.5 \wwClosedHole
    \vspace #-0.5 \wwClosedHole
    \vspace #-0.5 \wwClosedHole
    \vspace #-0.5 \wwClosedHole
    \vspace #-0.5 \wwClosedHole
    \vspace #-0.5 \wwClosedHole
  }
}

wwDiaClosed = \markup {
  \center-column { 
    \wwClosedHole
    \wwDiaLower
  }
}

wwDiaHalf = \markup {
  \center-column { 
    \wwHalfHole
    \wwDiaLower
  }
}

wwDiaOpen = \markup {
  \center-column { 
    \wwOpenHole
    \wwDiaLower
  }
}

{ c'4^\wwDiaOpen c'4^\wwDiaHalf c'4^\wwDiaClosed }
```

[image]

Comment: Great, perfect :-) Thaks a lot.